# Setting up multiple iOS phones for development

Tags: ios, iphone

I purchased the iOS developers license about a month ago. I set up my phone as a developer and have been testing on that, which has been fine. Now I am working on an app that uses bluetooth and i want to test it on a second device to make sure communication is working, but im not sure how to set up a second iPhone as a developer. I added another device onto my " "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" page and created a new provisioning profile and tried dragging it into iTunes and i get the error that it "Cannot be copied because it can not be played on this phone"

Im thinking i either have to set up another keychain for this second phone or i am dragging it into the wrong spot. if it is the keychain i don't know how to do it.

Comment: Open Xcode, select "Window->Organizer", find the new phone (assuming you plugged it in) click the button that says "Use For Development".  That should install your provisioning profile on your new device.  If that doesn't work then try navigating around in there and you should find your solution (maybe "Add to member center", etc...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are the one building the app then you should be able to install the app on the device via Xcode.  If you open up the organizer (window -> organizer) you should be able to select your device and enable developer mode.  From there is should be a build away.

If you're not the one building it then once you add the device to your account you'll need to also add that device as authorized on the provisioning profile.  Sort of a pain but it's the three step dance that apple requires.

There are a ton of other things that could go wrong as well and hopefully that is enough to get things working for you.